# Setting up apache and laravel

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel, ubuntu

So, when I go to my website:

```
<?php

/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylor@laravel.com>
 */

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for
| our application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
| into the script here so that we don't have to worry about manual
| loading any of our classes later on. It feels nice to relax.
|
*/

require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Turn On The Lights
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| We need to illuminate PHP development, so let us turn on the lights.
| This bootstraps the framework and gets it ready for use, then it
| will load up this application so that we can run it and send
| the responses back to the browser and delight our users.
|
*/

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request
| through the kernel, and send the associated response back to
| the client's browser allowing them to enjoy the creative
| and wonderful application we have prepared for them.
|
*/

$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

This is what I get, and I don't really know what is wrong. I am using apache2 on ubuntu server.

And this is my .htaccess.

[image]

Does anyone know what is wrong? rewrite is enabled and this .htaccess was working before not giving me any kind of problems but I feel like it is some error in it.

Comment: seems the error you got is not included in the question

Comment: what it might be? Or how to check where the error is?

Comment: It seems like your server is interpreting .php files as plaintext. I'm not sure why. I hope I helped.

Comment: Do other PHP files work?

Comment: Nope, how can I check/set what php apache should use, because I think that is the problem I do have webmin if you can do it from there